# How to book and use a GOL Brazil Airpass?

Tags: air-travel, tickets, airlines, brazil

I am looking into airpasses for domestic travel in Brazil. As far as I could find out, there only is the GOL airpass in Brazil right now (since TAM seems to have discontinued their airpass).

- How do I book a GOL airpass, when I have an international ticket to Brazil on BA? Is it possible online or do I need to go to travel agent?
- Once I have an airpass, can I book the flights online by myself or do I again need to see a travel agent?

Comment: Do you know this air company? http://www.voeazul.com.br/en/home

Answer (score 1):

According to GOL website,

"The Brazil Airpass must only be sold and ticketed outside Brazil", then, I assume that they just sell it by travel agents.

Anyway, here is the source, you can find more info:

http://www.voegol.com.br/en-us/agencias/Paginas/airpasses.aspx

Email: contatcus@golnaweb.com.br

About TAM, have you checked this website? https://www.tam.com.br/b2c/vgn/v/index.jsp?vgnextoid=122e65d4f9b13310VgnVCM1000009508020aRCRD

Looks like they sell the TAM Airpass

I found also a website to buy it, looks good: http://www.brol.com/airpass/

Comment: As far as I know you can only combine the airpass with an international flight to and from Brazil (you have to have a flight to Brazil and one back home). So asking your travel agency might  be the right thing.